# Get Grid Data Item in asp.net grid

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, datagridview

I wanted to get Grid Data Item in asp.net grid.In the similar procedure already i did in telerik like this,

```
 GridDataItem dataItem = (GridDataItem)e.Item; <-- this is Telerik Grid
```

I want the equivelent of the asp.net Grid

I need to do it for the below code,

```
 protected void gvTestRes_RowCommand(object sender, GridViewCommandEventArgs e)
{


    if (e.CommandName == "pdf")
    {
         //GridDataItem dataItem = (GridDataItem)e.Item;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I found it.Here i paste it for sometimes it maybe helpful to others

```
 string Id = gvBaptist.DataKeys[Convert.ToInt32(e.CommandArgument)].Value.ToString();
```